# How type mocks with vitest?

Tags: typescript, vitest

I want to mock `fs` with vitest and I am successfully doing so, however I am using `any` to do so. Consider

```
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';

vi.mock('fs')

it('can mock', async () => {
  // Property 'mockResolvedValue' does not exist on type '{ ......
  fs.readdir.mockResolvedValue([])

  // ok but can we do better?
  (fs.readdir as any).mockResolvedValue([])
})
```

How can I improve the typing here?

Comment: Vitest generally follows Jest's interface, does it have https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api/#jestmockedsource-options? (Edit: [yes](https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-mocked).)

Answer (score 5):

As @jonrsharpe pointed to in the comment, we can use this syntax:

```
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';

vi.mock('fs')

it('can mock', async () => {
  vi.mocked(fs.readdir).mockResolvedValue([])
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolve this by follow way

```
import { vi } from 'vitest'
import axios from 'axios';

// mock library
vi.mock('axios')

// mock library methods
const mockedAxios = vi.mocked(axios, true)
```

You can see this in vitest DOCS https://vitest.dev/guide/mocking.html#mocking

Answer (score 1):

I've been using `typeof` which is what I think @jonrsharpe was pointing you towards. Something like:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
const mockedFs = fs as Mocked<typeof fs>;
mockedFs.readdir.mockResolvedValue([]);
```